# Why is there no popular/notable/famous answer badge?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, badges, badge-request

I see that in all Stack Exchange sites (at least the ones I checked) there are [badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges) for Popular, Notable, and Famous Question, when it gets to 1k, 2.5k, and 10k views, respectively.

My question is **why are there no similar badges for Answers also?** Is it because the question is the one that caused the answers to also be seen?

I suspect that to be able to give those badges we should be able to *quantify* the views of an answer. Is it ok to assume that if some Question has `x` views then *all* answers from that question also have `x` views? Or only those highly upvoted or accepted?

Another option could be to count the views that Question gained since the posting of that answer, and assign that to be the number of views of a specific answer (this will also prevent new answers on famous posts to instantly get the badge). However I do not know how complex this type of queries could be.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> **why are there no similar badges for Answers also?**

Because view counts are only ever recorded for questions.

There is no reliable way to count answer views (given one usually needs to scroll down to them - there may be many answers, answers may end up being paged - that is several pages of answers etc..).

The short of it - we don't record view counts for answers, so cannot have a badge based on such a number.

---

Now, suppose we figure out a workable scheme for such a badge - we might not implement it after all.

The bottom line is - what behavior would this badge encourage? What would the point of it be? If it is something *already* covered by a different badge, it isn't something we would want to implement.

All I can see this doing is driving people directly to an answer - without reading the question. Which, frankly, isn't something good.

Comment: What about calculating it the way I asked, given that it is not a value recorded? By giving it to highly-scored answers, or make those views proportional to the votes or accepts of the answers.

Comment: Very inaccurate (and can change over time as people vote... - which hardly seems fair). And is certainly not fair on answers with low scores - that were still viewed a lot.

Comment: `what behavior would this badge encourage?` writing quality answers to questions and be rewarded in the future if the question becomes famous or significant in its network. It could be connected to the Famous Question badge, and award only *one* famous answer badge based on some criteria (votes, accepted...)

Comment: I suppose the "best" way to track is how many times someone follows an answer-specific link? But that seems like it would just make people want to spam links to their answers everywhere... also, didn't we have a hat for that?

Comment: That's my point. We **already** reward quality answers. With other badges.