# How can I search my own answers with different search filters?

Tags: support, answers, search

I know that I can search for my own answers/question by using:
`user:me`.

I also want to filter these questions/answers by the number of views.
Something like this:

`user:me views:100`

But the above query returns only my questions and not answers.

How can I return my unaccepted answers with more than 100 views?

I'm aware of the [search page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search).

Comment: Seems like the `views` filter only allows questions. Even `user:me views:100 is:a` returns questions only, even though I've specified I want answers.

Comment: @VLAZ is it possible to get them with some rest api? I knoe that people use sime extensions for so

Comment: I haven't tried, so I don't know. Perhaps you can do it with SEDE but it's not as convenient as the search.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching confirms that searches using `views:` will only return questions. SEDE will not be able to directly sort *answers* by views, since https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/298812/369802 confirms view counts are only ever logged for questions, never for answers. But it can sort your answers by the views of the questions they are under: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/264569/369802 (that query also seems to contain the questions you asked though)

Comment: @Tinkeringbell I did not know that there is a whole query language behind stackoverflow. Is this a playground https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new ?

Comment: @captain-yossarian Yes, I think you can play around there as much as you like. It might be interesting to you to take a look at [the help page](https://data.stackexchange.com/help), [this faq post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2677/369802) and some questions tagged [tag:data-explorer] before wading in though :)

Comment: @Tinkeringbell feel free to provide an answer. Thanks a lot for explanation

Comment: I'll leave the answering up to the people that can actually make a query that only returns answers.... Like I said, the stuff I linked is close, but it's not exactly what you asked for :)

Comment: @Tinkeringbell ok, understood.

Comment: See [my unaccepted answers with more than 100 views](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1462458?useriud=8495254)

Comment: @rene thanks, this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some search filters can only act on questions because answers don't have the attribute (or no sensible value in it). The criterion `views` is an example of that.

When a simple search won't satisfy your needs your next best option is [The Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/help), which comes with a [tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) written by the unforgettable [Monica Cellio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/162102/monica-cellio). The complete data schema can be found in [Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede).

I've gone ahead and created [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1462458/my-unaccepted-answers-with-more-than-100-views?useriud=8495254) for you:

```sql
select a.id  [Post Link]
     , a.score
from posts a
inner join posts q on q.id = a.parentid
where q.viewcount > 100
and q.acceptedanswerid <> a.id
and a.owneruserid = ##userid?8495254##
```

that lists your not accepted answers on questions with more than 100 views.

Keep in mind that SEDE is only updated once a week, on Sunday. If you need extra support or have a quick question we do have a [chatroom](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/data-explorer-sede) that is irregularly monitored for new messages.